# A linear map $T:V\rightarrow V$ can be written as $T=T_2T_1$ for some linear map $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map. Can you always write $T=T_2T_1$ for some linear maps $T_1:V\rightarrow W$, $T_2:W\rightarrow V$, where $W$ is some finite dimensional vector space and such that

1. $T_1$ is onto, $T_2$ is one to one?
2. $T_1$ is one to one, $T_2$ is onto?

First one true, if we put $W=Im(T)$, $T_1=T$ and $T_2=I$.

Second one is also true. But here $W$ will have larger dimension than $V$. So I am stucked in construction of $W$. Please help in constructing $W$ and accordingly $T_1$, $T_2$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $W=V\oplus V$, $T_1(v)=(v,0)$ is injective, $T_2(u,v)=T(u)+v$ is surjective and $T=T_2T_1$.