# Is rank$(T)$=rank$(T^*)$ even if $T:V\to W$ and $W$ not finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-maps

Suppose $T:V\to W$ is a linear map and $V$ is finite dimensional and $W$ is not necessarily finite dimensional. Is it still true that $Rank(T)=Rank(T^*)?$ Where $T^*$ is the dual map of $T.$

I know this would hold if $W$ is finite dimensional and so I thought about considering $T:V\to T(V)$ only rather than $W$ and then the 'range' would be finite dimensional. However I am not sure if this works and I am much interested in finding a better proof to this.

Many thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $T^*$? Does $V$ have any structure besides simply being a vector space, e.g. topological structure? For instance, is it a Banach space? A Hilbert space?

Comment: I was about to make comment on finite rank but Qiaochu's answer covers it. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3428671/81360) is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true more generally that if $T : V \to W$ has finite rank then $\text{rank}(T) = \text{rank}(T^{\ast})$. To see this abstractly, $T$ has finite rank $n$ iff it factors as a composite

$$V \xrightarrow{f} R \xrightarrow{g} W$$

where $f$ is surjective, $g$ is injective, and $\dim R = n$. Taking duals gives that $T^{\ast}$ factors as a composite

$$W^{\ast} \xrightarrow{g^{\ast}} R^{\ast} \xrightarrow{f^{\ast}} V^{\ast}$$

and taking duals takes injective maps to surjective maps and vice versa (this is not entirely formal in the infinite-dimensional case because taking duals is not an equivalence, so it needs to be checked) and $\dim R = \dim R^{\ast}$ so $T^{\ast}$ also has rank $n$.

This is badly false once $T$ no longer has finite rank. For example the rank of the identity $I : V \to V$ is $\dim V$ but the rank of its dual $I^{\ast} : V^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$ is $\dim V^{\ast}$ and this is generally larger than $\dim V$.

Comment: Thank you! This seems quite abstract, so could I please ask a few questions? Would $f$ and $g$ have to be linear as well? This seems a bit counter intuitive to me and so apologies

Comment: @JustWandering: yes, this whole argument is taking place in the category of vector spaces, so $f$ and $g$ are linear.